# DynamicData - How to use a SourceList<> with a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I'm trying to use DynamicData `SourceList<>` as a datasource for a `DataGrid`.

All of the documentation I've read states that I should implement something along the lines of ...

```
private readonly SourceList<MyThing> Things;
public IObservableCollection<MyThing> ThingsBindable { get; }

Things = new SourceList<MyThing>();
ThingsBindable = new ObservableCollectionExtended<MyThing>();
Things
    .Connect()
    .Bind(ThingsBindable)
    .Subscribe();
```

And here's where my problems start!

The `SourceList<>` doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` which forces me to bind `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `ThingsBindable`. But when I add an item to the DataGrid via the UI, the item gets added to `ThingsBindable` but that isn't reflected in the underlying `SourceList<>`.

I feel like I must be missing a big piece of the puzzle ...

---

**UPDATE**

@Glenn it's not multithreaded (not yet anyway!).

I've added the following code to feed the differences back to the `SourceList<>` ...

```
var collectionChanges = Items.ToObservableChangeSet();
//
collectionChanges.Subscribe((changeSet) =>
{
    SourceItems.EditDiff(Items);
});
```

... but now, when I add an item via the UI, the following error is thrown on the `SourceItems.EditDiff(Items)`.

> Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event

Weirdly, it seems the underlying collection does get the new item added despite the error being thrown.

Comment: Do you do any multithreading adding to your source list btw. The example with a simple bind with no mutation with only one thread adding you would just need the ObservableCollectionExtended. You can get a change set observable by doing ToObservableChangeSet on your bindable collection. You can then do EditDiff to get the changes back into your main SourceList

Comment: @glenn thanks (again!) for your help. Please see my updated question :0)

Comment: Dynamic Data is well suited for handling dynamically changing collections using linq style operators in a thread safe manner.  Following on from  Glenn's question, unless you are.doing something which requires thread safety, you are probably better off directly using an observable collection as  DD does not attempt to replace the standard observable collection.

Comment: @RolandPheasant - thanks for your response (great library by the way!!). I wanted to use DynamicData because I have several different data sources that need to be combined into one list when presented to the user ... I thought DynamicData was a good fit, but there's no reason why I can't just use the classic `ObservableCollection<>`! Thanks.

Comment: Also, I have requirements where i need to recalculate aggregate totals when properties of the objects in the collection change ... another reason I was heading in the direction of Dynamic data ... will probably end up reverting to `ReactiveList<>`!

Comment: I understand now. You have complex requirements as data is from multiple sources. The part that DD does not directly handle is adding rows to the data grid. One solution which I have used previously is to disable the new row line on the data grid and manage adding new rows in code. It's a little tricky to implement as you will need to determine what triggers adding a new row. In my case when a user edited the new row and hit enter, I would commit the row and add a new one manually.